# reinstall the bare theme without reinstall the complete Shopware 5.4.6

Tags: themes, shopware

my bare theme in Shopware 5.4.6 looks suddenly without colors, css, ...
[image]

therfore i want reinstall the bare theme without reinstall the complete Shopware 5.4.6

how could i reinstall the bare theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the installation package of your version and upload the "themes" folder to your shopware installation and override the existing files. But this won't solve your problem, because the Bare theme is designed to have no javascript and CSS content. It is a plain HTML theme, where you can add your individual css and js files.

**Responsive:**
[image]

**Bare:**
[image]